# pyreverse: How to set output directory for generated diagrams

Tags: python, pyreverse

Documentation on pyreverse is sparse and half of the pages that google presented me, redirect to some *exotic* pages that will require some explaining should your boss find them in your browser history.
Due to the way how pyreverse seems to work, you have to use it from inside your root project/django app directory (running it when in, say, `MyApp/docs/` may not find every ancestor of a class your interested in). Meaning the generated diagrams will 'clog' up your project folder unless you manually move them elsewhere.

Is there a way to designate an output folder for pyreverse?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is now possible since pylint-2.7.3 with the `output-directory` option.

For example:

```
pyreverse -ASmy a.py --output-directory <path to directory>
```

Alternatively:

```
pyreverse -ASmy a.py -d <path to directory>
```

Please see `pyreverse --help` for this information.

Answer (score 0):

Well man, the only way I found is scripting...

```
mkdir -p docs/uml
pyreverse -ASmy -o png -p myproj .
mv *.png docs/uml
```

Maybe you can write your own setup.py script. In the old way of make.

./my_setups.py docs

Answer (score 0):

When you run it via a Python [`subprocess`](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/subprocess.html) call you can **specify a working directory**:

```py
import subprocess

# Possibly put this into a loop to analyse all your files
subprocess.run("pyreverse -AS -o png " + filePath + " -p " + fileName, shell=True, cwd="path/to/output/directory")
```

Note that you may have to correct your `filePath`s (by prepending `../`s to it) if it is relative.